# place images on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I have an canvas which draws from Video Tag of HTML5. How can i place images on canvas which already has another image,

```js
video.addEventListener('canplay', function(ev){
    if (!streaming) {
      height = video.videoHeight / (video.videoWidth/width);
      video.setAttribute('width', width);
      video.setAttribute('height', height);
      canvas.setAttribute('width', width);
      canvas.setAttribute('height', height);
      streaming = true;
    }
  }, false);

  function takepicture() {
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height);
    var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    photo.setAttribute('src', data);
    }

  startbutton.addEventListener('click', function(ev){
   takepicture();
    ev.preventDefault();
  }, false);
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <video id="video"></video>
  
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <button id="startbutton">Take photo</button>
  
 </div>

<div class="container">

 <span>
  <img src="http://www.pageresource.com/clipart/clipart/fashion/hats/Panama_20hat.png"/>
  <p>Image 1</p>
 </span>
 <span>
  <img src="http://www.pageresource.com/clipart/clipart/fashion/hats/hat-01.png"/>
  <p>Image 2</p>
 </span>
 <span>
 
 </span>
 
</div>
```

EDIT 1: The Canvas contains an image which is taken as screenshot from video element. THere is a div class = container with few images . When user selects/clicks a particular image , it should be placed on the canvas , which already contains an image(screenshot taken from video element).

How to place user selected image on the image on the canvas ? (Its not a replace, but a scenario like hat on the user face-placing selected hats on the user face screenshot)

Comment: you want to replace the image???

Comment: As ManjunathSiddappa says, your question is not clear. If you just want to draw another image over the existing content, you can do another `.drawImage(newImage,x,y)`

Comment: @markE Have added more details of the question